# Thunderbird + ldap write support

Tags: ldap, thunderbird

Is there anyone aware of someone seriously working on thunderdbird to get write support on ldap shared addressbook?

Comment: Probably no one since that isn't working since Netscape Communicator got the ability to read LDAP trees for address books 20000 years ago.

Comment: you are right but in this way there is noway to get a shared and writable addressbook. Isn't it weird? Mail clients like Claws and Evolution have write support since ages while Thunderdbird, which is the only one working well on Windows, still lacks this feature.

Comment: Bad things happen in a bad world. It's open source. So you can make it a better world.

Comment: I wish I could, but I can't. Not enough skills ...

Comment: Then pay someone to do it.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86405 tracks work in progress on this feature.  Apparently the backend is already done, but UI is not.